# HTML submit button with forward slash in the onClick

Tags: javascript, html, input, onclick, submit

I have a very simple form that uses a forward slash in the input button onClick portion. This is a built in form for an application that we use. The application uses IE to process the form.

```
<BODY onLoad=setFocus(this)><FORM NAME=fMU METHOD=GET ACTION="http://HammerHead/MU">
<TABLE>
    <input type="hidden" name="Beat/Sta" value="">
    <tr>
        <td COLSPAN=2>
            <input type=SUBMIT onclick="this.form.Beat/Sta.value='B01'" value="BF1" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE=RESET VALUE="Clear" /></TD>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

When using the "Beat/Sta" value in the form it does not pass the "B01" value. Because of the "/". I receieve a script syntax error code 0.

I have another button in a separate form that works perfectly but looks like the below, with no "/" in the onClick:

```
<input type=SUBMIT onclick="this.form.Location.value='home'" value="Home" />
```

That button works fine and passes the location value of "home"

I've tried to use quotes, double quotes, multiple forward slashes,etc... to try and make sure the / is passed to the function but nothing seems to recognize the "Beat/Sta" value. I can resolve the script errors using quotes but it still will not pass the B01 value to "Beat/Sta"

Comment: This is untested, but try escaping the "/" in your onclick call <input type=SUBMIT onclick="this.form.Beat\/Sta.value='B01'" value="BF1" />

Comment: an element name in html should not have a '/' slash. Script is failing to access the element by this name. replace the slash in name with underscore Beat_Sta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
document.getElementsByName('Beat/Sta')[0].value='B01'
```

Your whole code will be:

```
<BODY onLoad=setFocus(this)><FORM NAME=fMU METHOD=GET ACTION="http://HammerHead/MU">
<TABLE>
<input type="hidden" name="Beat/Sta" value="">
<tr>
<td COLSPAN=2>
<input type=SUBMIT onclick="document.getElementsByName('Beat/Sta')[0].value='B01'" value="BF1" />
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT TYPE=RESET VALUE="Clear" /></TD>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

But it will be better if you avoid using special characters in names and identificators

Comment: perfect!! That did it

Answer (score 0):

In programming languages, including html, symbols are often used as "special characters", meaning they are not treated as simple characters anymore but they have specific functions.
Think of the symbols you use around each tag (< and >).

As you can see in your own code the '/' is often used to close an existing tag (e.g. ). This lets you know that in html '/' is not a simply forward slash but a specific 'function'.

If you want to use special characters as part of a string, a variable name or else. You need to do something called **escape** said character. Escaping means letting the code know you are not using the special function associated with said character but you instead want to use the character as a plain character.

In html you have to use special codes to replace special characters.
Have a look on this page for a list of HTML escape character:
[HTML escape characters](https://www.werockyourweb.com/html-escape-characters/).

Same for javascript, you need to use something to let the code know you want to use your '/' as a simple character. Check this link on how to escape in JS: [JS escape character](https://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm)

**However**, as a rule of thumb, try to avoid using special characters if you can. As already mentioned in the comments '_' (underscore) is a good alternative.